# Poincare constant for Gaussian distribution

Tags: functional-analysis, normal-distribution, concentration-of-measure

The minimum of constant $C$ to satisfy the following condition is called Poincare constant for a probability measure $\mu$.
For any smooth function $f$ on $\mathbb{R}$, the relation
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty (f(x)-E[f])^2 \mu(dx) \le C \int_{-\infty}^\infty f'(x)^2 \mu(dx) $$
holds,  where $E[f]$ is the expectation of $f(X)$.
It seems that Poincare constant for 1-dimensional Gaussian distribution is known. However, I cannot find its value and its suitable reference. I am seeking the answer for this question.

Comment: A reference is Chapter 4.1 in Bakry, Gentil, Ledoux's book "Analysis and geometry of Markov diffusion operators".